# Loading million rows into partitioned Stateful service

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I'm trying to load 20 million rows into partitioned stateful service ReliableDictionary. I partitioned stateful service into 10 partitions. Based on MSDN documentation, I understood that I need to use some hashing algorithm to find the correct partition and send data to it to load into IReliabledictionary. So I used the [Hydra](https://github.com/turowicz/Hydra) to get the partition number based on the value. All I'm storing is a `List<long>`  in the `IReliableDictionary`.

So I created a Stateless service as wrapper,

1. which will fetch the rows from the SQL Server (20 million),
2. get the partition number using [Hydra](https://github.com/turowicz/Hydra) for each row,
3. group them by partition number
4. call the Stateful service for each partition using ServiceRemoting. However, I get `fabric message too large` exception if I send 1 million rows of data per each request so I chunked it into 100000 per request.

This is taking 74 minutes for it to complete. This is too long. Below is the code for uploading -

Please advise.

```
 foreach (var itemKvp in ItemsDictionary)
            {
                var ulnv2Uri = new Uri("fabric:/TestApp/dataservice");


                //Insert to the correct shard based on the hash algorithm 
                var dataService = _serviceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IDataService>(
                dataStoreUri,
                 new ServicePartitionKey(itemKvp.Key), TargetReplicaSelector.PrimaryReplica, "dataServiceRemotingListener");

                var itemsShard = itemKvp.Value;
                //if the total records count is greater then 100000 then send it in chunks
                if (itemsShard.Count > 1_000_000)
                {
                    //var tasks = new List<Task>();
                    var totalCount = itemsShard.Count;
                    var pageSize = 100000;
                    var page = 1;
                    var skip = 0;
                    while (skip < totalCount)
                    {
                        await dataService.InsertData(itemsShard.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList());
                        page++;
                        skip = pageSize * (page - 1);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                   //otherwise send all together
                    await dataService.InsertData(itemsShard);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What does your IReliableDictionary look like? When you say you're storing a List<long> in the IReliableDictionary, do you mean it's a IReliableDictionary<string, long> or are you storing something along the lines of IReliableDictionary<string, List<long>>?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely save some time here, by uploading to all partitions in parallel. 
So create 10 service proxies (one for each partition) and use them simultaneously.

Comment: I tried parallel calls inside itemsShards.count > 1m condition. but that was ending up with timeout errors.  I will try parallel call at partitions level and let you know.

Comment: After adding parallel calls it reduced to 30 mins now. Is this usual time for uploading data in SF Reliabledictionary?